# How to reindex column names (1,4,6) to include extra numbers? (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe, showing hours and days of when emails were sent. This was created via pandas `pivot_table()`

The column names are the hours. Index is the day. Values are number of emails sent :

[image: df]

Is it possible to re-index the columns to include all hours? From 0 to 23. This would increase the number of `nans`, but that's fine. I don't expect emails to be sent 1am on Sunday.

I have tried to use `reindex()`, creating the new set of columns first:

New columns. This is a list starting from `0` to `23`.

```
new_hours = [i for i in range(0,24)]

print(new_hours)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Now I will attempt to reindex, but I get a value error:

```
df_rides_day_hour3 = df_rides_day_hour3.reindex(labels=detailed_hours, axis=1)

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
```

I have attempted to use the `level` argument, but it doesn't help.

If you need the dataframe, I have pasted it using `df.to_dict()` here: https://pastecode.xyz/view/b5f45b52

Picot table code. 'day_sent' is just name of day string. `hour sent` is integer. `is_sent` is all `1`.

```
df_rides_day_hour3 = pd.pivot_table(df[['day_sent', 'hour_sent', 'is_sent']], index=['day_sent', 'hour_sent'], aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: What is your `pivot_table` code?

Comment: I'll add it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code not working, because `MultiIndex` in columns with one first level only `is_sent`. So is possible remove it by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df_rides_day_hour3 = (df_rides_day_hour3.droplevel(0,axis=1)
                                        .reindex(labels=range(24), axis=1))
```

Or you can avoid `MulitIndex` by changed `pivot_table`:

```
df_rides_day_hour3 = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                                    index=['day_sent', 'hour_sent'],
                                    columns='is_sent',
                                    aggfunc='size')
df_rides_day_hour3 = df_rides_day_hour3.reindex(labels=range(24), axis=1)
```

Comment: `ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.`

Comment: @SCool - opps, I forget `axis=1`